# Can a principal ideal generated by a polynomial with unit leading coefficient contain nonzero elements of lesser degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

This came up as part of a proof I'm trying to write. Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ over a ring $R$ with identity. If its leading coefficient is a unit (i.e. has a multiplicative inverse), can the principal (two-sided) ideal $(P)$ contain nonzero polynomials of degree less than $n$? I strongly suspect the answer is no. It's clearly impossible in the case of commutative $R$, but the noncommutative case is proving surprisingly difficult because the characterization of principal ideals isn't as nice.

Can anyone spot a proof, or if I'm mistaken, a counterexample for noncommutative $R$ (preferably as elementary as possible; I'm still fairly new to ring theory)?

Comment: Are you considering left ideals or right ideals or two-sided ideals?

Comment: @AnginaSeng two-sided ideals. Apologies; my book simply uses "ideals" to mean "two-sided ideals", as a quick google showed me. I'll update the question

Comment: $b(X+a)-(X+a)b=ba-ab$?

Comment: Oh, yes, that would be one. I'll have to think through why this proof isn't working, then, as I know the result is true independently. Thanks!

Comment: Following @JCAA 's comment on his answer, suppose that $X$ is not assumed to be central in the definition of polynomial ring.  Then $(X^2-a)X-X(X^2-a)=Xa-aX$ provides a counterexample (with the obvious interpretation of degree).

Answer (score 1):

I guess your rings are commutative. Then the ideal $I$  generated by  a monic polynomial $f(x)$ has Groebner basis $\{f(x)\}$. If  a polynomial $g(x)\in I$, the highest term of $g$ must be divisible by the highest term of $f(x)$ so degree$(g)$$\ge$degree$(f)$.

Comment: I think the OP was familiar with this argument already.  His question was specifically about non-commutative rings and @AnginaSeng gave (in my view) the best answer possible in the comments.

Comment: Now I see that the OP does talk about non-commutative  rings. But then it is not clear what a polynomial is. There are several non-equivalent definitions. Also the word "two-sided" appeared in the OP after I posted my answer.

Comment: Good point (+1): The answer in comments does not work if you do not assume the indeterminate is central.  I interpreted (I think correctly) that the OP meant for it to be central, but it is not stated.

Comment: I am not sure "central indeterminate" is the most frequent assumption when people define polynomials over non-commutative rings. I would call a polynomial an element of the free $R$-algebra of rank 1.